# Classify, except isomorphism, all covering spaces with 2 sheets over the space $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Classify, except isomorphism, all covering spaces with 2 sheets over the space $\mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$

I know that $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2)=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ that its abelian.

I have found $p_1: \dfrac{S^2 \times S^2}{c_1} \to \mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$ and $p_2: \dfrac{S^1 \times S^1}{c_2} \to \mathbb{RP}^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2$

where $c_1= {(a,1)|a^2=1}$ and $c_2= {(1,b)|b^2=1}$

But I have one missing, since in my homework the teacher said so. Can someone tell me which one? thanks!

Comment: What about the diagonal subgroup in $Z/2\times Z/2$ ?

Comment: Hi @Thomas, can you help me constructing the covering space, please.

Comment: what is isomorphish? I've never heard of this before

Comment: sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** consider $(S^2 \times S^2)/{\sim}$ where $(x_1,x_2) \sim (-x_1,-x_2)$.

I believe this is the orientable double cover of $\mathbb RP^2 \times \mathbb RP^2$ which is nice.

Comment: Fun fact:  This double cover of $\mathbb{R}P^2\times \mathbb{R}P^2$ is the Grassmannian of $2$-planes in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Answer (score 1):

So, resuming what you guys said this would be my proof:

Since $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2)= \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ its abelian. So $Conj(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2)$ are the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ with index 2

Let $A= <(a,1)|a^2=1>$  and $B=<(1,b)|b^2=1>$

The action of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$  in $S^2 \times S^2$ its continous and properly discontinous.

Then $\pi : S^2 \times S^2/ \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ is a covering space and since $S^2 \times S^2$ its simply connected, its the universal covering.

So the covering spaces of two sheetes are:

$p_1: S^2 \times S^2/A \to \mathbb{RP}^2\times  S^2 $

$p_2: S^2 \times S^2/B \to  S^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2  $

and let $X : (S^2 \times S^2)/∼$  where $(x_1,x_2) \sim (-x_1,-x_2)$

then $X \to \mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ such as $[(a,b)] \to ([a],[b])$.

where $[x] =\{ x, -x\}$

but can I say that $S^2 \times \mathbb{RP}^2 \cong \mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ and   $\mathbb{RP}^2  \times S^2 \cong \mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$

because $\mathbb{RP}^2  \times S^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ with $([a],b) \to  ([a],[b])$ and $S^2  \times \mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{RP}^2\times \mathbb{RP}^2$ with $(a,[b]) \to  ([a],[b])$

Comment: There's some notation that needs to be cleaned up.  For example, what do you mean by $\pi:S^2\times S^2/\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\cong ...$.  Shouldn't there be a $\rightarrow$ somewhere?  And do you really want the domain to be $S^2\times S^2$ with some stuff modded out?  Lastly, what do you mean in your line begining with "can I say...."?  The maps you wrote down afterwards are coverings, but not homeomoprhisms, so I'm not sure what you mean by $\cong$.